# Textview overflow

Tags: android-layout, android

I have a layout which has and ImageView to the left, and TextView to the right:

```
<ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/alert"
        android:id="@+id/articleStoryImage" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/articleStorySubTitle"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
         />
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/articleStory"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/articleStorySubTitle"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/articleStoryImage"
   android:gravity="right"                  
   android:inputType="textMultiLine"        
   android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
   android:ellipsize="end"
   android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
   android:textSize="11sp"
   android:textColor="#000000" />
```

What I'm trying to do, is that the TextView text would start to the right of the ImageView,
but would continue below the ImageView. You can call it some kind of overflow.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

EDITED: FULL XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/articleStoryTitle"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
       android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
       android:typeface="sans"
       android:gravity="right"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:singleLine="false"   
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"             
       android:textSize="25sp"  
       android:textColor="#DBA118"
       android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/articleStorySubTitle"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/articleStoryTitle"
       android:gravity="right"                  
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"        
       android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
       android:textSize="12sp"
       android:textColor="#000000"   
       android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/alert"
            android:id="@+id/articleStoryImage" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/articleStorySubTitle"        
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
             />
    <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/articleStory"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/articleStorySubTitle"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/articleStoryImage"
       android:gravity="right"                  
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"        
       android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
       aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
       aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
       android:textSize="11sp"
       android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what u specified for your layout orientation?

Comment: I'm using RelativeLayout

Comment: please post once your full xml file

Comment: r u specified for your layout android:orientation="horizontal" like this.

Comment: your code working correctly to me.the textview is alighned right to the imageview only.wat's your problem.can u tell me clearly

Comment: I want the text to the right of the image would overflow to below the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you may get better solution but you can ckeck this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  
 <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/tv"   
    android:layout_width="200dp"  
    android:layout_height="150dp"  
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView011"   
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"  
    android:text="hi every body hi every body hi everybodyend"                        
    android:textSize="20dp" />   
 <ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/ImageView011"   
    android:layout_width="100dp"   
    android:layout_height="100dp"   
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"  
    android:background="@drawable/imag" />
 <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="350dp"   
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"    
    android:text=" TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView"                  
    android:textSize="20dp" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

also check this link : http://dev.androidteam.ru/snippets/textview/leadingmarginspan2